# Fetching data from excel sheet in Truclient lite (script recording tool)

Tags: truclient

How do we fetch data/inputs from the excel sheet while recording script using the Truclient lite script recording tool?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in TruClient Lite, as you cannot access the file system from a browser extension.
You can use parameters to store values and retrieve them during script replay

Comment: So in that case, do we have any shortcut wherein we can just copy the data from the excel sheet to the parameter fields in Truclient Lite??

Comment: In VuGen, you can import parameters from a CSV file. In TruClient Lite this is not currently possible.